# не могу решить задачу с тремя числами которые вводятся через консоль в python

Tags: python

только начинаю учить python и попалась такая задача.
нужно ввести три числа через консоль. первое называется А, второе В, третье С.
до третьего числа нужно досчитать от единицы и вывести это на экран.
Если во время перебора чисел число кратное А, то выводится А, если кратное В, то выводится В, если число кратное АиВ то выводить АВ.
например ввели 2, 5, 18

```
1 А 3 А B А 7 А 9 АВ 11 А 13 А В А 17 А
```

у меня получается только так, подскажите пожалуйста в каком направлении двигаться и как решить задачу

```
a = int(input('A: '))
b = int(input('B: '))
ab = int(input('AB: '))

if ab > a or ab > b:
    i = 0
    while i != ab:
        i += 1
        if i == a or i % a == 0:
            print('A')
        if i == b or i % b == 0:
            print('B')
        if i % a and i % b == 0:
            print('AB')
        print(i)
```

Comment: начнем с того, что вас не устраивает в вашем коде?

Comment: код должен заменять кратные числа на буквы, у меня выходит что он выводит все числа и буквы вместе
1
A
2
3
A
4
B
AB
5
A
6
7
A
8
9
A
B
10
11
A
12
13
A
14
B
AB
15
A
16
17
A
18

Comment: уберите последний print

Comment: тогда он убирает все числа
A
A
B
AB
A
A
A
B
A
A
B
AB
A
A
кручу верчу, а понять не могу(

Comment: так и надо в задании, разве нет?

Comment: Я вообще задание так и не понял, как не пытался.

Comment: в консоли нужно ввести три числа, (условно  а,в,с), нужно от единицы досчитать до третьего числа.
если число кратное а, то вместо числа вывести А, если кратное в, то вывести В и тд пока не дойдет до третьего введенного числа.

например ввели 2, 5, 18

выведет
1 А 3 А B А 7 А 9 АВ 11 А 13 А В А 17 А

Comment: А, всё, теперь дошло )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (i % a == 0) and (i % b == 0):
     print('AB')
elif i % a == 0:
     print('A')
elif i % b == 0:
     print('B')
else:
    print(i)
```

Comment: Вам удалось понять задание?! ))

Comment: Да, это [задача foobar](https://www.hackerearth.com/ru/problem/golf/foobar/) переформулированная. Придумана кем-то из известных программистов для собеседований, чтобы понять, что человек вообще способен писать код и продумать логику.

Comment: спасибо большое!

Comment: А, ну Foo Bar задачу знаю, а в такой формулировке еле дошло про что речь )

Answer (score 1):

Реализация с использованием словаря

```
from random import randint

a, b, c = 2, 5, 10
while c > 0:
    c -= 1
    i = randint(1, 1000)
    print(f'Исх. число {i}, новое значение:', {1: 'A', 2: 'B', 3: 'AB'}.get((i % a == 0) + (i % b == 0) * 2, i))
```

```
Исх. число 461, новое значение: 461
Исх. число 170, новое значение: AB
Исх. число 898, новое значение: A
Исх. число 872, новое значение: A
Исх. число 310, новое значение: AB
Исх. число 636, новое значение: A
Исх. число 801, новое значение: 801
Исх. число 218, новое значение: A
Исх. число 699, новое значение: 699
Исх. число 540, новое значение: AB
```

Comment: а если числа рандомные? условие что нужно ввести через консоль, а там можно ввести что угодно